# Xamarin.Forms ListView AutoHeight in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I have ListView with ViewCell and it's ViewCell contains Label with huge text. How can I make an auto-height ViewCell???

Screenshot of issue 
[image: Screenshot of issue]

My XAML code:

```
    <ContentPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Physis.Movements_And_Interactions_Page" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Physis">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
    <ToolbarItem  x:Name="settings" Text="{Binding settings_text}" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>


     <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20" x:Name="Main_View2" >
            <ListView x:Name="Main_Menu" ItemsSource="{Binding Planets}" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Key=backgroundColor}" SeparatorColor="{DynamicResource Key=textColor}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
             <ViewCell >

              <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
               <Label Text="{Binding Name}" StyleClass="Body"/>
               <Label Text="{Binding Description}" StyleClass="Body"/>               
             </StackLayout>

             </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
              </ListView>

      </StackLayout >
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `HasUnevenRows="true"` on your ListView. See documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows?view=xamarin-forms